# Angular 4. Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, npm

Then i'm start the app by command `ng serve`    in console i see error:

```
VM1018:2297 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
            at eval (<anonymous>)
            at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
            at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../popper.js/dist/popper.js (popper.js?6efa:1)
            at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 88f7324…:54)
            at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:66)
            at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 88f7324…:54)
            at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 88f7324…:25)
            at scripts.bundle.js:1
        webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports  @   addScript.js:9
        ../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../popper.js/dist/popper.js @   popper.js?6efa:1
        __webpack_require__ @   bootstrap 88f7324…:54
        2   @   scripts.bundle.js:66
        __webpack_require__ @   bootstrap 88f7324…:54
        webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap 88f7324…:25
        (anonymous) @   scripts.bundle.js:1
```

Just start then angular application, install: bootstrap, jQuery, popper.js and then add styles & scripts files to angular-cli.json/angular.json

angular-cli.json/angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "Web"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "build",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

i'm use:

```
node 8.4.0
npm 5.3.0
jquery 3.2.1
bootstrap 4 beta
```

Where i'm make a mistake?
Some text or something else for post this questing with large part of code (my english is very bad, i know...)

My package.json have this:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add entire file of angular.cli.json

Comment: done, fix question (add fully json file)

Comment: can you add package.json

Comment: Robert, I'm add package.json

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: thanks, i'll wait = )

Comment: if you need you bootstrap in your application use this package https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: this package must be used in *.ts files, but this isn't good (css & js from third-party packages must be builded with `ng build`, but not with import in component)  or i'm wrong?

Comment: I'm getting this same error in angular 8. Is popper.js the only reason for it ?

Comment: @KedarKulkarni no, popper is only one possible reason for it. Try to offline all included scripts in .angular.cli.json and after it uncomment each script row and launch server. One of scripts fail our build

Comment: I'm getting syntax error in scripts.js. Its giving error on import { } from '' line

Comment: @KedarKulkarni create ticket with more information and i will try to help u

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found answer. 
In `./.angular-cli.json` at the row `scripts` change folder from:
`"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js"`

> to this (if you use modern version of webpack):

`"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js"`

> else this:

`"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"`

Thanks [fezVrasta](https://github.com/fezvrasta)

Comment: My hangup was that I was loading *\node_modules\popper.js\dist\popper.js*,  when I should have been loading 
__\node_modules\popper.js\dist\umd\popper.js__

Comment: super answer :)

Comment: this `"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"` worked for me

Comment: But how do you know which to use?

Comment: Truly, what a catch!!! umd worked for me. So, what are the other two then?

Comment: simply calling all the versions in turn and checking the errors in the console

Comment: excellent answer. umd worked for me. Not sure how did u find that

Comment: @PratapA.K thanks)) speak with fezVrasta who develop popper.js = )

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server again.

Comment: I did the same mistake and forgotten to add the proper path for popper.js, and got the same error, but change the path and add the umd/popper.js it working now. thanks your problem solution save my time...

Answer (score 2):

this is perfect working on angular4/6, i have tested it in my projects.

```
"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me in Angular7

```
["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",  
 "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",  
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working on angular 9
In angular.json just change

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: That worked :) Thank you. I have forgotten to add `umd` in the `poppoer.min.js` path.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me in Angular 13 as well.

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in Angular 8

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

            ]
```