# Couldn't add Bootstrap 4, jQuery, and PopperJS libraries to .angular-cli.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

Currently i'm trying to implement **Bootstrap 4** `navbar` element on my **Angular 5** project, and it needs three JS libraries, Bootstrap 4, jQuery, and PopperJS.

It works **flawlessly (i.e. NO ERROR occurred)** when I add following to `src/index.html`

```
<head>
...
...
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

**However,** I wanted to do an experiment by adding those **three JS libraries** to the `.angular-cli.json` (instead of using CDN on `src/index.html`), so I did following:

On `.angular-cli.json`, i add:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"        
      ],
```

Note: before adding those three scripts to `.angular-cli.json` I already installed Bootstrap 4, jQuery and PopperJS packages using `npm`.

When running it, there is an Error on console (Chrome Dev Tool)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export         scripts.bundle.js:2302
```

When clicking on the error message it brought to this line

```
export default Popper;
```

I'm kinda confused on what's happening and what's the real cause of the problem?
How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you created any providers?

Comment: Not yet, do i need to?

Comment: Try changing the popper script link to `"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js"`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092871/angular-4-unexpected-token-export

Comment: as it turns out, the one that is working is `umd` not `esm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `npm install --save bootstrap jquery popper.js`
2. angular-cli.json:

   ```
     "styles": [
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
       "styles.css"
     ],
     "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
     ],
   ```

Now u can launch your app